# Running make with a mixture of single-threaded and multi-threaded recipes

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile, openmp

I have a makefile that compiles and runs a fairly large set of programs, to produce output. Some of the programs are single-threaded, and some use OpenMP to run on multiple CPU cores. Quite a few of the tasks take a long time to run, so it would be useful to pass a "-j" option to make, to allow the single-threaded programs to be run in parallel. However, the OpenMP tasks already use all available CPU cores (and quite a lot of RAM), so they should be run one at a time.

Is there a flag that I can attach to the tasks that use OpenMP in the makefile that prevents other tasks running in parallel to it, while allowing other tasks to run in parallel at other times? I think the .NOTPARALLEL special target completely disables all parallelism.

Comment: http://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?5108 is exactly what I'm looking for, but hasn't been incorporated into GNU make. Any further ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possibilities:

1) make will not run tasks in parallel if they depend on each other.
So you could try to trick make by adding false dependecies to the targets that you want to run alone. For exemple, declare that your OpenMP targets depend on the output of all the serial ones.

2) you could maybe also split your Makefile into two different ones: one for OpenMP targets that will not run in parallel, and one for the serial ones. This implies that you don't have cross dependencies between OpenMP and serial targets.

3) split the compiling and the running. Use a bash script to run things as you wish.

Comment: 1 is undesirable and a hack, and would cause recipes to be rerun when not necessary. The whole point of using a makefile is to only rebuild the ones which have changed.

Comment: 2 - tell me more about this - unfortunately some serial recipes do depend on some OpenMP recipes, and vice-versa.

Comment: 3 - then I wouldn't have a way to build the whole lot under the control of make, making sure to only rebuild the recipes that have changed.

Comment: Looks like your dependencies make it a tough problem. What about using a file for interprocess communication ?
You could use a wrapper script that checks for a lock file, if present sleep a few second, if not, create it and run your OpenMP program. Delete file at end of script.
The Makefile should delete it at the very beginning to avoid dead locks.

Comment: I had thought of that. At the moment, I have adapted the gnu make patch above to the latest version (which wasn't hard) and compiled a new make. We'll see how that pans out. Unfortunately there isn't any quick and easy way to encourage the make maintainers to include the patch, even though it is ready and waiting.